# how to load a huge json file with Pycharm in windows 10?

Tags: python, json, nlp, pycharm, windows-10

I am a prospective graduate student studying deep learning.
I ran the code below on my macbook. The result was success. All json files are loaded and processed well.
I figured it would be faster if I processed the data with a lab computer with a bigger 16gb ram.
However, it was not executed in Windows as a `Memory Error` occurred.
I set Windows virtual memory paging size and Pycharm vm size  following advice on the internet. but error was not solved.

[virtual memory paging file size setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW6rU.png)

how to run the code below in Windows Desktop? and why the code does not run in the Desktop though it has bigger RAM?

## Settings

My computer settings are as follows:

**Individual Notebook**

- m1 silicon Macbook Air
- 8gb ram
- 256gb storage

**Desktop in Lab**

- Windows 10 Education
- 16gb ram
- 256gb ssd, 1TB hdd storage

**requirements.txt**

- python=3.8.12
- pysimdjson=4.0.3
- pandas=1.3.5

**json file**

- NXLS~.json (2.39gb)
- SXLS~.json (1.06gb)

## Code

my codes are as follows:

```
import simdjson
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import trange


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # json key names corresponding to column names
    mapping_key = ['doc_index', 'begin', 'end', 'word_id', 'word', 'pos', 'sense_id']         
    # dataframe column name
    columns = ['sentence', 'target_index_start', 'target_index_end', 'target_word_id', 'target_word', 'target_pos', 'sense_id']
    corpus = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    # read .json dataset.
    data_path = './dataset'
    NXLS = 'NXLS2002104060.json'
    SXLS = "SXLS2002104060.json"

    with open(data_path + '/' + NXLS, "rb") as f:
        nxls_doc = simdjson.loads(f.read())


    with open(data_path + '/' + SXLS, "rb") as f:
        sxls_doc = simdjson.loads(f.read())

    # parsing
    sentences = []
    WSDs = []
    for i in trange(len(nxls_doc["document"])):
        for j in range(len(nxls_doc["document"][i]["sentence"])):
            sentence = nxls_doc["document"][i]["sentence"][j]["form"]
            sentences.append(sentence)
            wsd = nxls_doc["document"][i]["sentence"][j]["WSD"]
            for k in range(len(wsd)):
                wsd[k]["doc_index"] = j
            # wsd[(k for k in range(len(wsd)))]["doc_index"] = j
            WSDs.append(wsd)

    for i in trange(len(sxls_doc["document"])):
        for j in range(len(sxls_doc["document"][i]["sentence"])):
            sentence = sxls_doc["document"][i]["sentence"][j]["form"]
            sentences.append(sentence)
            wsd = sxls_doc["document"][i]["sentence"][j]["WSD"]
            for k in range(len(wsd)):
                wsd[k]["doc_index"] = j
            # wsd[(k for k in range(len(wsd)))]["doc_index"] = j
            WSDs.append(wsd)

    # list -> Dataframe (restructure)
    for i in trange(len(WSDs)):
        wsd = WSDs[i]
        for j in range(len(wsd)):
            row = []
            doc_index = wsd[j]["doc_index"]
            row.append(sentences[doc_index])
            #for k in range(len(columns)-1):
            row.extend([wsd[j][mapping_key[k+1]] for k in range(len(columns)-1)])
            #corpus[columns[k+1]] = wsd[j][mapping_key[k+1]]
            corpus.loc[len(corpus)] = row
```

## Result

**Mac**

[result1 in m1 silicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thuoy.png)

[result2 in m1 silicon. because of the speed of processing, I stopped it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zYkg.png)

[json successfully loaded in m1 silicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vw8K.png)

**windows**

[result in Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GU0EP.png)